undefined error not raising NameError and program runs fine
Why is my code here not raising a NameError or Syntax error when I clearly am using non existing error name?
def fun(x):
    assert x >= 0
    return x ** 0.5

def mid_level(x):
    try:
        fun(x)
    except ButtError: 
        print(333)
        raise
    print(444)

try:
    x = mid_level(-1)
except RuntimeError:
    x = -1
except Exception:
    x = 9
except:
    x = -2

print(x)


except Exception: is catching the exception that ButtError is not an existing exception.

@001 I don't think that's it, I tried to reproduce without the second except and didn't get an error.

If I add some code to print what's happening inside the except Exception block I get the error NameError: name 'ButtError' is not defined

@001 I see the fault in my test, I didn't generate the assert exception that this question does.

@001 good point. I did except Exception as e: print(e) and I was able to see it is handling the NameError exception. I've an idea now. Thank you

@001 I think you have enough explanation to create an actual answer.

Already answered, which is fine. I got sidetracked running the code on ideone which is using version 3.9.5 which has a completely different result: https://ideone.com/0JyJtW

@001 Please answer it, so I can accept.

As already answered in the comments by @001 ,
try:
    x = mid_level(-1)
except RuntimeError:
    x = -1
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    x = 9
except:
    x = -2

print(x)

the print statement will result in NameError
name 'ButtError' is not defined

so the except Exception is handling the NameError exception and not the assertion exception.

The except clause in Python is used to catch specific exceptions. In this case, you are using ButtError in the except clause, which is not a built-in or existing error type. However, this does not cause a NameError immediately because Python does not evaluate the name of the exception (e.g., ButtError) unless the exception is actually raised. The code runs up until an exception is triggered, and only then does Python check whether the exception being raised matches any of the except clauses.
